# How to boot Android into Custom Recovery Mode?

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp

I am trying to boot Android into a custom recovery(TWRP). I rebooted the Android device holding the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power keys</kbd> but it doesn't work and shows  a weird screen with yellow colour palette on it and it can't be turned on. I tried following this [How To Boot Android Into A Custom Recovery (TWRP, CWM, Philz Touch)](http://techchomps.com/how-to-boot-android-into-a-custom-recovery-twrp-cwm-philz-touch/) but it still doesn't boot. Any help?

Comment: Could you please state brand and model of the Android device you're using? As you can find out in our [recovery-mode tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info), the answer depends on this.

Comment: The same guide says if _Volume down + Power_ didn't work, try _Volume up + Power_. Have you tried that?

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you're using a Samsung model. Its  <kbd>volume up</kbd>  +  <kbd>home button</kbd>  +  <kbd>power</kbd> .

Comment: What lead you to assume that OP uses a Samsung device?

Comment: @Firelord ask why the OP didn't specify it instead of asking me that.

Answer (score -2):

On My Android Device It Is **Volume Up** + **Power** Or On Samsung It Is **Volume Up** + **Home** + **Power**.